# String to octal in c++

Tags: c++, string, octal

```
String hexstr = "0x12AB450912AB450912AB450912AB450912AB4509";
```

I have a string which has 40 bytes in length.

I need to convert the above string to octal (to 20 bytes)

```
char *endp;
strtoul(hexstr , &endp, 8);
```

To use the above function, it works for long i.e for 8 bytes.
But my string is 40 bytes.

Can some body tell me how to convert to octal and store back to string?

Comment: actually 1 hex is 4 bit but as str it's 1 byte...so convert the string to a serial of bits, it's only 20-byte. I believe this is what OP means.

Comment: Can you add some more text on the desired input/output relation, e.g., can you provide example input/output?

Answer (score 1):

the function returns an unsigned long int, so the max it will return is `8` bytes, assuming it doesn't go crazy trying to convert a `40` byte string. no standard integer type holds `40` bytes. you can do this by converting the digits to binary and reading every 3 bits to get the octal version of this number